# How to get details of grouped object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5 app and in this app I got four models.
User, Report, Trip and Expense.

User has_many Reports, trips and expenses
Reports has_many trips and expenses.

I want to get a JSON response with all the trips and expenses that a user has done this month, grouped by Report.

I can do this but I need only the Id and Title of the report (when grouping) and now I get only the object name.

**I use this method (located in the User model):**

```
def grouped_reports
    trips = self.trips
    expenses = self.expenses
    items = trips + expenses
    items.group_by(&:report)
  end
```

**The output in JSON is this:**

```
{
    "#<Report:0x007fa225163ba8>": [{
            "id": 12,
            "account_id": 20,
            "user_id": 92,
            "vehicle_id": null,
            "ttype": null,
            "description": "saf",
            "start_latitude": 57.4874919,
            "start_longitude": 12.0761927999999,
            "end_latitude": 59.3293235,
            "end_longitude": 18.0685808000001,
            "start_address": "Chicago",
            "end_address": "New york",
            "distance": 490,
            "time": null,
            "status": "pending",
            "registered_at": "2018-08-24T02:00:00.000+02:00",
            "approvals_count": 0,
            "rejections_count": 0,
            "created_at": "2018-08-24T22:39:22.637+02:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-24T22:39:22.637+02:00",
            "report_id": 79,
            "return_trip": null,
            "triptype_id": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "account_id": 20,
            "user_id": 92,
            "cost": 100,
            "etype": null,
            "description": "sdsd",
            "start_address": null,
            "end_address": null,
            "distance": null,
            "reimbursable": false,
            "status": "pending",
            "registered_at": "2018-08-08T00:00:00.000+02:00",
            "created_at": "2018-08-24T22:39:40.343+02:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-24T22:39:40.343+02:00",
            "approvals_count": 0,
            "rejections_count": 0,
            "report_id": 79,
            "expensetype_id": 15
        }
    ]
}
```

*There is two things I need to improve.*

- Display id and title of report not .
- Get only this months reports.

**Update, this works but is it the right way in terms of performance?**

And not only performance, is it actually using the title of the report as a grouping factor? Which is not good since may reports can share the same title. I want to group by report_id but display report title.

```
def grouped_reports
    trips = self.trips
    expenses = self.expenses
    items = trips + expenses
    items.group_by{ |t| [t.report.id, t.report.title] }
  end
```

Comment: `Display id and title of report not ` what do you mean by this?

Comment: The Report object got an Id and a Title and I want to display then (at least the title) but now I get #<Report:0x007fa225163ba8>.

Answer (score 1):

Code would differ depending on what JSON format you want to output.

I usually use json generator such `jbuilder`, but this time I suggest a array and hash structure.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reports
  has_many :expenses
  has_many :trips

  def grouped_reports
    start_date = Time.current.beginning_of_month
    monthly_trips = trips.where('created_at >= ?', start_date)
    monthly_expenses = expenses.where('created_at >= ?', start_date)

    report_ids = (monthly_trips.map(&:report_id) + monthly_expenses.map(&:report_id)).uniq
    reports = Report.where(id: report_ids)

    reports.map do |report|
      {
        id: report.id,
        title: report.title,
        trips: trips.select {|t| t.report_id == report.id},
        expenses: expenses.select {|e| e.report_id == report.id}
      }
    end
  end
end
```

1. You are grouping with `trips` and `expenses` joined to one array, but it is not preferable to put different types in same arrays for JSON. It would be safe to have a hash format and separate key for `trip` and `expense`.
2. To extract records for this month, use `where` to filter.
3. It is possible to fetch `trips` by using `includes` for `reports` and `expenses`, but from a performance point of view it is better to get the related `trips` at once.

If you want to further improve performance, narrow down only columns used when outputting JSON by using `select` method. This would be a huge improvement if a lot of records are outputted.

Comment: Thank you! I am using jbuilder so I just ended up like this: https://www.pastiebin.com/5ba8ec98ebe8e